# How to convert List<String> to objects in response with other format

Tags: java, spring, list, object, response

I have respone like

"preferentialManufacturingRegionCode":

[
"Brest",
"Vitebsk",
"Gomel",
"Minsk",
]

```
How to convert List of strings to objects that in respone will be like

"preferentialManufacturingRegionCode": [
                    
                            {
                                "value": "Brest",
                            },
                            {
                                "value": "Vitebsk",
                            },
                            {
                                "value": "Gomel",
                            },
                            {
                                "value": "Minsk",
                            },
]
I will be grateful for your answer
```

Comment: Hmmm.... that looks like JSON but it isn't

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it.

Comment: yes, it json format

Comment: Nope, it isn't. You can't have fields in an array

Comment: but if i can change to 
"preferentialManufacturingRegionCode": [
                    {  "value"  :"Брестская область",}
                     {  "value" :"Витебская область",}
                    {   "value" :"Гомельская область",}
                     {  "value" :"Гродненская область",}
                     {  "value" :"Минск",}
                      { "value" :"Минская область",}
                      { "value" :"Могилевская область"}
                            ]
also will be good

Comment: Well do it then

Comment: how? this is a main question :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Define a class `Value`:

```
public class Value<T> {
    private final T value;
    
    public Value(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

You can now convert your `List<String>` as follows:

```
    List<Value<String>> values = list.stream()
            .map(Value::new)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

UPDATE:

Use a JSON generator to produce JSON. For example, with Jackson:

```
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.writeValue(System.out, values);
```

Output:

```
[{"value":"Brest"},{"value":"Vitebsk"},{"value":"Gomel"},{"value":"Minsk"}]
```

Comment: but if i want to convert to type like : "value:"key".. ?

Comment: Use a JSON generator

Comment: See my update above

Comment: yes, it is working. But  i can't set to List<String>. How can i convert List<Value<String>> to List<String> ?

Comment: @АндрейАндрей why would you want to do that? you just converted a `List<String>` into a `List<Value<String>>`

Comment: because I need to set preferentialManufacturingRegionCode to get the response that I need, but according to the model, he wants a list of strings. The model cannot be changed, otherwise a lot of things will break, here the option of solution like to create converter of types or convert list of Values to list of strings {"dsf", "sdfd"} and set to list, but i dont known how to do it

Comment: @АндрейАндрей You have an input model, use an output model for the version with `List<Value<String>>` instead of `List<String>`.